# Ruby 2.0.0 p195 and [-p247]?

Tags: ruby, version-control, rvm

just a quick question, I am upgrading from Ruby 1.8.7 to 2.0.0 but looking in terminal I see:

```
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p374]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p448]
[ruby-]2.0.0-p195
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p247]
[ruby-]2.0.0-head
```

What do the numbers at the end mean (p448, p195, p247, head...etc) does it matter which I install? Thanks for the help. I'm still new to Ruby.

Comment: "p" stands for "Patch".

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell what does the `head` mean?

Comment: The "head" is pulling the most recent trunk. It is the version that has not been released yet and hence doesn't yet have a patch number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruby versioning scheme goes `Major.Minor.Tiny` So, in `1.9.3`, `Major = 1`, `Minor = 9`, `Tiny = 3`. The "pxxx" behind it stands for the specific build number of "Patch Level." The higher the number, the more recent the patch. If a security breach is found in Ruby, you will see the Ruby team push out a patch. You will do wise to keep your Ruby version at the highest patched version.

The "Head" at the end of the last item is the most recent version of the development branch of Ruby. I would recommend against this unless you are needing to test against the newest changes. This gives you the option of pulling down version `2.1.0` even though it has not been released yet (at the time of this writing).

For detailed information about "Head" and other features in RVM when it comes to installing versions of Ruby, see [RVM's Installing Ruby Page](http://rvm.io/rubies/installing)

Also note that you can always see what the most recent trunk of Ruby is in the [`version.h`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/version.h#001) of the source code.